# Automated SFTP upload with curl

Tags: curl, sftp

I want a file to be uploaded daily to remote server using automated ftp command. Can someone please help me on this below command to check whether it's right or wrong?

```
curl -Tu username:password /path/to/dir/*(om[1]) sftp://sftp.example.com/remote/dir
```

where

- `username:password` is my own username and password.
- `/path/to/dir/*(om[1])`: to get the latest(updated) file from my local dir
- `sftp://sftp.example.com/remote/dir`: secure file transfer

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run this, what have you done to get the answer so that you know first if it is right or wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your command line has a problem that you can check on the [man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).
Basically you need to separate the `-T <file to be uploaded>`  from the `-u <user:password>`.
In the end your command line should look more like:

```
curl -T /path/to/dir/*(om[1]) -u username:password sftp://sftp.example.com/remote/dir
```

I am not sure about the actual meaning of the regular expression you mention `*(om[1])`, though.

Of course, in case SFTP is used, you can use a private SSH key for authentication instead of username and password as per `--key` and `--key-type` options. See documentation linked above for details.

Finally, the question is about **`FTP`** while the command line example is about **`SFTP`**, but this shouldn't change the solution I am proposing.

Comment: Does this still work with ssh keys? Aside from the fact that specifying passwords on command lines is insecure, ssh keys are more secure still.

Comment: Yes, of course they do.

Comment: **Update:** For SSH keys you want something like `--key path/to/key --pubkey path/to/key.pub` for specifying the private & public SSH keys respectively.

Comment: When you connect to a server via SFTP/SCP/SSH you don't mind about public keys: those need to be already in place in the server. I updated my answer to reflect the "ability".

Answer (score 3):

Why not rsync instead?  You may have to install it (use your package manager), but it's made for this kind of thing.

```
RSYNC_PASSWORD='password' rsync -rtv /path/to/dir/ username@sftp.example.com:remote/dir
```

-r will recursively rsync, -t preserves time stamps so existing files aren't re-uploaded (effectively), and -v is verbose.

If you create and copy your ssh public key, you won't need to do the `RSYNC_PASSWORD='password'` part.

If you don't have a public/private key combination, run:

```
ssh-keygen
```

Then

```
ssh-copy-key-id username@sftp.example.com
```

This assumes your remote server supports connecting and updating the `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys` file; otherwise, you'll have to manually upload the `authorized_keys` file with your public key.

This assumes you're running a recent version of linux.  Unix systems like Mac OS don't have the `ssh-copy-key-id`.  Here's some more information on generating and installing your public key on a remote host:

http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html

Comment: Your point is irrelevant, as OP uses a curl command.

Comment: One downside with rsync is that it requires a shell account, something that SFTP doesn’t require. I.e. more attack surface.